# linking of If Else Statements with picker

Tags: swift, xcode

Beginner coder here. I have a question with Xcode. I am developing a horoscope app and have a question on linking my If Else Statements with picker input values.

The logic in the app currently is, User selects date listed, hits button, and an alert message pops up containing specific copy related to their input. How would I get my if else statements to print in the alert message?

TLDR; Need help with linking function print value with alert window message

Here is a sample of how it currently looks, I am also getting an error of [Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'String?'] in line 3 here. Thank you in advance!

```
   let message = signselection()


    let alert = UIAlertController (title: "Your Astrological Sign is...", message:message, preferredStyle: .alert)

let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) {(action) -> Void in} 

func signselection () {
        if (curMonth == 0) {
            if(curDay! < 20) {
                print("Capricorn Message")
            } else {
              print("Aquarius Message")
            }
        }

    if (curMonth == 1){
        if(curDay! < 19)  {
            print ("Aquarius Message")
        } else {
            print ("Pisces Message")
        } }

    if (curMonth == 2){
        if(curDay! < 20)  {
            print ("Pisces Message")
            } else {
                print ("Aries Message")
        } }
```

Answer (score 0):

The signselection() method only prints the message, but it should return a string. That's why you're getting the error saying that it can't cast void, "()", to String. The function declaration should be:

```
func signSelection() -> String
```

and in stead of print("Message") you should

```
return "Message" //where "Message" is each message you're currently printing
```

You should also add the okAction to there alert with:

alert.addAction(okAction)

Comment: I changed it, and it got rid of my errors but somehow the correct text still won't link up the values. The printed text is now just "message"

Comment: So you should be returning a string that contains your message, and not literally "message". Could you add your updated code to the question?